# Removing duplicates from sqldatasource

Tags: c#, sql-server, duplicates, sqldatasource

I'm trying to create a "Contact Us" page and I have a drop down list on this page using a SqlDataSource to pull the list from my database but my database has duplicate entrys that I do not want shown on the list, Is there anyway I can remove the duplicates? I cant for the life of me figure it out.

Here is my currect code, Thanks.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList2.Visible = false;
    DropDownList3.Visible = false;
}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ID = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex +1;
    string _courseID = ID.ToString();
    StringCollection idCollection = new StringCollection();
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM TB_Chapter WHERE c_CourseID = '" + _courseID + "' ";
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
    DropDownList2.Visible = true;
    DropDownList3.Visible = false;
}
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="m_ModuleName" DataValueField="m_ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OpenIT_DBConnectionString3 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TB_modules]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="c_ChapterName" DataValueField="c_ChapterID"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OpenIT_DBConnectionString3 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TB_Chapter] WHERE ([c_CourseID] = @c_CourseID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="c_CourseID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="c_ChapterTopicName" DataValueField="c_ChapterTopicID"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OpenIT_DBConnectionString3 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TB_Chapter] WHERE ([c_ChapterID] = @c_ChapterID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="c_ChapterID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why would your database have duplicates? I could see de-normalizing a warehours, but somehow I don't imagine that's what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TB_Chapter WHERE c_CourseID = '" + _courseID + "' "`

Answer (score 0):

use `DISTINCT` keyword.

---

```
WITH UniqueChapterxxx AS
    (
        SELECT m_ID, m_ID,xxx,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m_ID ORDER BY m_ID) AS 'RowNum'
        FROM TB_Chapter WHERE c_CourseID = '" + _courseID + "' "
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM UniqueChapterxxx
    WHERE RowNum = 1
```

[Check This Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

---